# Do..end loop just returning main array

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, pry

Can anyone help me to find problem here?

```
    @deals.each.with_index(1) do |deal, i|
  binding.pry
  puts "#{deal.title} - #{deal.price} - Rating: #{deal.deal_rating}"
  # puts "Available for #{deal.price}"
  # puts "Rating: #{deal.deal_rating}"
  # puts "#{deal.title}"
  # puts "Available at "
end
```

If I do binding.pry, and try to check the value of deal here, it is returning me complete @deals array rather than one deal.

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: That's weird. `deal` should be an element out of `@deals` array. What do you need `i` for? You're not using it in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just `each_with_index` which will give you the object and the index inside the total of elements being iterated:

```
<% @deals.each_with_index do |deal, i| %>
  <% binding.pry %>
  <%= "#{deal.title} - #{deal.price} - Rating: #{deal.deal_rating}" %>
<% end %>
```

This way inspecting with `pry` you take the first element from `@deals`:

```
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fe0cd161ee8>>)> @deals.first
=> #<Deal:0x007fe0cb2751d8
 id: 1,
 title: "Deal-0",
 price: 764,
 deal_rating: 93,
 created_at: Sat, 01 Apr 2017 15:00:29 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 01 Apr 2017 15:00:29 UTC +00:00>
```

If you want to do it in your views then use `unless` to check for the first element using the `index`:

```
<% @deals.each_with_index do |deal, i| %>
  <% unless !i.zero? %>
    <%= "#{deal.title} - #{deal.price} - Rating: #{deal.deal_rating}" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The difference is that with `with_index` you can use an optional parameter to offset the starting index, so you're specifying the index from where to start with `with_index(1)` not trying to get the first element, see this:

```
<% @deals.each.with_index(2) do |deal, index| %>
  <%= "#{index}: #{deal}" %><br>
<% end %>

2: #<Deal:0x007fe0cb55ca90>
3: #<Deal:0x007fe0cb55c950>
4: #<Deal:0x007fe0cb55c810>
...
```

This starts from the `index` 2, and the other one from 0.

```
<% @deals.each_with_index do |deal, index| %>
  <%= "#{index}: #{deal}" %><br>
<% end %>
0: #<Deal:0x007fe0cb55ca90>
1: #<Deal:0x007fe0cb55c950>
2: #<Deal:0x007fe0cb55c810>
3: #<Deal:0x007fe0cb55c6d0>
4: #<Deal:0x007fe0cb55c590>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. You solved my error! Once again, thanks a lot. :-)